# jquery css function adding to base amount instead of resetting it

Tags: jquery

I wish I could provide and example of this other than the following code and explanation of my problem...

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $("footer").css("margin-top", ($(document).height() - 191) + "px");
    });
```

I would expect this to cause the footer's margin to be reset every time the page is resized. But its not. Its added. It responds as if I am using "+=" instead of just resetting it.

I came up with a way around it, but it doesn't allow me to set a minimum margin.

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $("footer").css("margin-top", 0 + "px");
        $("footer").css("margin-top", ($(document).height() - 191) + "px");
    });
```

Why isn't this resetting the margin-top? anyone know? When its pulled out, nothing happens to the footer so I don't think it is conflicting code.

**Edit**
I know that position:absolute; bottom:0; fixes this issue mostly(keyword) but I wasn't sure why the margin-top issue took place to begin with. Mostly an educational question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you add `margin-top`, you are making the document longer, so the height increases.

Consider trying `window.innerHeight - 191`, if that's the kind of effect you're after. Alternatively, you might have better luck with `position:absolute; bottom: 191px;` or similar.

Comment: You know, that makes sense, I just figured it would only be one step behind instead of each previous state. But I get why it would. I'll just have to throw in an if statement to catch a minimum amount. Thank you. Marking this the answser for explaining why its happening. This will allow me to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Is the footer floating, or otherwise outside of normal page flow? If not, the margin will be the distance between the footer and anything else on the page.

Why not position the footer by setting `bottom: 0px`?

Comment: Something my other coworkers used on this site disabled min-height on this page(atleast for the html, body, and document) and I dont want the footer to smash into things. but good idea.